# MySQL foreign key constraint not applying?

Tags: mysql, constraints

I have the tables `Players` and `PlayerMeta`

```
mysql> DESCRIBE Players;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| PlayerName  | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| Birthdate   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Location    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FirstName   | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Whitelisted | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE PlayerMeta;
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID             | int(5)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| JoinDate       | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| BuildQuota     | int(2)     | NO   |     | 2       |       |
| RegisteredDate | date       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| HideBirthdate  | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to execute this command, and it returns Query OK:

```
ALTER TABLE PlayerMeta
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_PlayerID
FOREIGN KEY (ID)
REFERENCES Players(ID)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Yet, when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE PlayerMeta`, it does not show the constraint, nor is it in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Any thoughts? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is `SHOW CREATE TABLE PlayerMeta`:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE PlayerMeta;
... a bunch of lines ...
| PlayerMeta | CREATE TABLE `PlayerMeta` (
  `ID` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `JoinDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `BuildQuota` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `RegisteredDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HideBirthdate` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

EDIT(2): The problem was `ID` in `PlayerMeta` was already a primary key and a foreign key would not apply in conjunction with it.

Comment: So show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` as well

Comment: Has the command executed successfully ?? Did you get any errors ??? have you refreshed after creating the constraint ???

Comment: @M.Ali: "and it returns Query OK:". PS: "have you refreshed after creating the constraint" --- what does this even mean?

Comment: its like when you create a table you cant see it in the object explorer until you right click and refresh the list. its there but you dont see it until you refresh it

Comment: @M.Ali This is the command line. No refreshing here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot make the column `PlayerMeta.ID` be both a `PRIMARY KEY` and a `FOREIGN KEY`. If that is the design, 1:1, the tables should probably just be combined anyway.

Comment: Opss my bad its mysql dont know why I thought it was sql-server

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will not permit you to create a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on a column which is itself a `PRIMARY KEY`.  If your design is such that the two tables share a one-to-one relationship and both hold information about a `Player`, it may not make sense to separate them and instead combine both tables into one.

In any case, if you wish to keep them separate and enforce a `FOREIGN KEY` relationship on them, you need to remove the `PRIMARY KEY` on `PlayerMeta.ID`. You may still have a `UNIQUE`, non primary key index on it.

Comment: It doesn't explain "and it returns Query OK". Whereas it **IS** possible to have a column to be a PK and a FK simultaneously. I just created it without any issues. I have no idea how this could be an answer. http://pastebin.com/FfH7b5dt

Comment: @sibble you ought to unaccept this so I can remove it. It isn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create foreign keys for MyISAM.

Only InnoDB supports them.

So the solution for you is to change the storage engine for both tables.

```
ALTER TABLE Players ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE PlayerMeta ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then re-apply your `ALTER` with adding a FK constraint.

Comment: You can create them in MyISAM, but they are not enforced, I believe.

Comment: Interesting. I did as @MichaelBerkowski suggested above about removing the primary key from `ID` in `PlayerMeta`, and the foreign key applied fine.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: I doubt so http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Comment: @zerkms It will happily create them, but not actually enforce them which is super-misleading http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/836c2/1

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: exactly. That's why the issue is with engine, not with having PK (which is valid)

Comment: @sibble You should unaccept my answer and accept this instead. InnoDB really is the solution here.